# Python - iterating over a list and passing each element as a parameter to a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been going through the DataQuest "Introduction to Python" program, and in the "Modules" section of the course, there's a section on defining functions.  I got through that section but then decided I wanted to try to extend it.  The original code, which works, is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import csv

f = open("nfl.csv", 'r')
nfl = list(csv.reader(f))

# Define your function here.
def nfl_wins(team):
    count = 0
    for row in nfl:
        if row[2] == team:
            count += 1
    return count

cowboys_wins = nfl_wins("Dallas Cowboys")
falcons_wins = nfl_wins("Atlanta Falcons")

print(cowboys_wins)
print(falcons_wins)
```

My code, which is intended to iterate over a list containing all the teams and give the number of wins for each team, is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import csv

f = open('nfl.csv', 'r')
nfl = list(csv.reader(f))

# Define your function here.
def nfl_wins(team):
    print(team)
    count = 0
    for row in nfl:
        if row[2] == team:
            count = count + 1
    return count

nfl_teams = ['Denver Broncos', 'Detroit Lions', 'Green Bay Packers', 'Houston Texans', 'Indianapolis Colts', 'Jacksonville Jaguars', 'Kansas City Chiefs', 'Miami Dolphins', 'Minnesota Vikings', 'New England Patriots', 'New Orleans Saints', 'New York Giants', 'New York Jets', 'Oakland Raiders', 'Philadelphia Eagles', 'Pittsburgh Steelers', 'San Diego Chargers', 'San Francisco 49ers', 'Seattle Seahawks', 'St. Louis Rams', 'Tampa Bay Buccaneers', 'Tennessee Titans', 'Washington Redskins']

for squad in nfl_teams:
    print(squad, nfl_wins(squad))
```

When I just iterate over the "nfl_teams" list and print the names, it works fine.  When I try to pass the team names to the "nfl_wins" function, I get the following error:

```
$ python3 nfl_wins.py
Denver Broncos
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nfl_wins.py", line 20, in <module>
    print(squad, nfl_wins(squad))
  File "nfl_wins.py", line 13, in nfl_wins
    if row[2] == team:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

My environment is Python 3.4.3 on Cygwin running  under Windows 7 Enterprise.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything obviously wrong here. You may have accidentally changed your CSV, or used the wrong one.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
Your given code fails for lack of the CSV file; please hard-code the data into your example, so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to check my csv file.  I had bad characters in there that were causing the code to fail.  I fixed that, and the code works fine now.  Thanks again.